# How to pass ang2 @ngrx/store to http interceptor to alert app of 401/3?

Tags: angular, ngrx

Is it possible to pass the redux store to an interceptor in angular2? I need to trigger application change when the user's session has expired and figured the easiest way would be via the redux store.

Here is my interceptor class:

```
@Injectable()
export class CrowdHttp extends Http {
    constructor(
        backend: ConnectionBackend,
        defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
        private _router: Router,
        private store: Store<any>)
    {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
        return observable.catch((err, source) => {
            console.log( this.store );
            if (err.status  == 401 ) {
                this.store.dispatch(new NewLoggedInUserAction(null));
                return Observable.empty();
            } else {
                console.log( err );
                this.store.dispatch(new NewLoggedInUserAction(null));
                return Observable.throw(err);
            }
        });
    }
```

But the said class is included in the providers of the main app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        StoreModule.provideStore(
            StoreLoader.reducers(),
            StoreLoader.initialState()
        ),
        StoreDevtoolsModule.instrumentStore({
            monitor: useLogMonitor({
                visible: BootstrapDataService.reduxStoreDebug(),
                position: 'right'
            }),
        }),
        StoreLogMonitorModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        CrowdComponent,
    ],
    bootstrap: [CrowdComponent],
    providers: [
        AuthGuard,
        BootstrapDataService,
        AuthService,
        AuthResolver,
        {
            provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
            useValue: window.crowdRoute
        },
        {
            provide: Http,
            useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions, router: Router) => new CrowdHttp(xhrBackend, requestOptions, router, store),
            deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router]
        },
        {
            provide: BrowserXhr,
            useClass: CrowdBrowserXHR
        }
    ]
})
export class CrowdModule {
    constructor() {
        //optionally do something magical at this point...
    }
}
```

The catch works nicely, but i cannot find a way to pass the event back out to the rest of the application. The store passed does not contain the dispatch function and throws an error: `this.store.dispatch is not a function`

Am i approaching this in the best way or is there a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your current setup of the `http` provider in `app.module.ts` with the following lines:

```
{
    provide: Http,
    useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions, router: Router, store: Store<any>) => new CrowdHttp(xhrBackend, requestOptions, router, store),
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router, Store]
}
```